# MultiSelectField in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose, I have a list of professionals. I need to filter them based on their availability(Monday, Tuesday...etc). For example, a professional can select Monday and Tuesday as his available days. How can I implement this in Django models. Is there any way? NB : I'm not refering to Django Forms or MultiChoiceFields or Choice fields. Also I'm using Django 1.9, Is there anyway to use the widget django-multiselectfield in here successfully. Coz I've already tried all possibilities. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=django+multiple+choices

Answer (score 1):

I would propose something like this:

```
DAY_CHOICES = (
    ('01', 'Sunday'),
    ('02', 'Monday'),
    # etc
)

class Professional(models.Model):
   # add smth here


class Record (models.Model):
    professional =  models.ForeignKey(Professional, null=True),

    availability = models.CharField(
        _('available'), max_length=10,
        choices=DAY_CHOICES,
        blank=True, null=True,
    )

class Timetable (models.Model):
   record =  models.ForeignKey(Record, null=True),
```

So you will be able to filter either professionals or days or both